# Need instructions to deploy Corda 4 on AWS

Tags: corda

We have already deployed Corda 3.1 on AWS few months back. Now with Corda 4 we do not have a jetty server on individual node anymore. But we got a separate client folder to run Springboot. The Corda website https://docs.corda.net/aws-vm.html also does not give us a clue on the deployment part on AWS. Can anyone guide on this please.

Answer (score 0):

To run a web server via Spring Boot, you have two options:

- Run it on the same instance as your node. This is then just another java process running on the aws instance and should be the simpler solution in terms of deployment.
- Run it in another instance. This will require playing around with your aws config (I'm not strong in this area) to allow your node instance + your web server to connect to each other.

Both of these can use docker if you wanted to but running java processes directly is also fine.